# Exceeding a TrueCrypt volume size

Tags: truecrypt

When using TrueCrypt, you have to declare a size for the file upon creation of a new volume. What happens if the files encrypted in that volume grow to exceed the declared size?

*Example of editing a file*: A volume is created with a size of 1MB. Initially, there is a 1kb text file in it. Then, I edit it and add enough data that the file now exceeds 1MB. What happens when the file is saved and the TrueCrypt volume is dismounted?

*Example of adding a file*: A volume is created with a size of 1MB. Initially, there is nothing in it. I mount the volume, add a file that's too big (say, a 2MB mp3 file). What happens when the volume is dismounted?

Will there be a warning message? Will the data be silently dropped?

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a file that's too big (you would get a "Drive full" error). This is just the same as with any other volume. The same holds true when trying to save a file that has grown too much - you wouldn't be able to save it.

Therefore, there's no problem when dismounting the volume, either.

Comment: So it would be an alert message that pops up upon doing Ctrl+S in, for example, MS Word?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Why not just try it?